# Freebase GUID return null value on online search

Tags: freebase, mql

I have some GUIDs extracted from freebase and I am looking for their specific names . When I use online freebase query editor, the engine search just returned me the "mid" of the object. I put some GUID here as a sample.

```
/guid/9202a8c04000641f800000000081a20e  
/guid/9202a8c04000641f8000000000d01105
/guid/9202a8c04000641f8000000000ee5691
```

I would like to know which query is suitable to retrieve information by having only GUID. I tried

```
{"id": "/guid/9202a8c04000641f8000000000ee5691",
"name":null,
"*":null}
```

but the result is empty for some GUIDs like this

```
  "result": [{
    "permission": "/boot/all_permission",
    "name": null,
    "key": [],
    "mid": "/m/0838jg",
    "guid": "#9202a8c04000641f800000000081a20e",
    "timestamp": "2006-10-23T12:41:35.0000Z",
    "attribution": "/user/metaweb",
    "id": "/m/0838jg",
    "creator": "/user/metaweb",
    "search": [],
    "type": []
  }]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible for Freebase entities to not have a name.  This is usually true of the CVT or mediator nodes, but in this case it's a topic which was deleted.  If you look at the [historical view of the object](https://www.freebase.com/guid/9202a8c04000641f800000000081a20e?links&lang=en&historical=true) you can see that it used to be a list of U.S. presidential pets.  Freebase excludes Wikipedia list articles (because they don't represent a single entity), so it got deleted.

If you want to query the name as it was before it was deleted, you could use the as_of_time parameter with your query.

EDIT: Here are examples of [MQLRead](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread/?as_of_time=2012-01-01&lang=/lang/en&query=%5B%7B%20%22guid%22%3a%20%22#9202a8c04000641f800000000081a20e%22,%20%22%2a%22%3a%20%5B%7B%7D%5D%20%7D%5D) and the [query editor](https://www.freebase.com/query?as_of_time=2012-01-01&lang=/lang/en&q=%5B%7B%22guid%22%3a%22#9202a8c04000641f800000000081a20e%22,%22%2a%22%3a%5B%7B%7D%5D%7D%5D)

Comment: Thank you so much Tom for your comprehensive answer. My problem is solved with your hint.Freebase is an awesome resource but it is a bit complicate like mapping n dimensions relational data into two dimensions :)

Comment: Tom can you give me an example how to use as_of_time  since I could not call it out of Freebase online editor. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's an envelope parameter, not a query parameter.  I've updated my answer with links to examples.  Look in the Query Envelope tab in the query editor to see where the date was added.